# Configure HTML element to behave like text character

Tags: css, word-wrap, contenteditable, custom-element

Is it possible to configure an HTML element (custom element or built-in) to be treated like a single text (non-whitespace) character -- that is, it has an implied `<nobr>` wrapped around itself and adjacent text.

My use case is making certain musical symbols that are treated like text (like the sharp in `F#` but more complex).  So I could write `the note F<my-sharp></my-sharp> is nice` and know that there would never be a line break between `F` and `<my-sharp>`, equivalent to `the note <nobr>F<my-sharp></my-sharp></nobr> is nice`.  The css `white-space: nowrap` would configure anything inside `<my-sharp>` but not apply to the `F` behind it.

I want to avoid the `<nobr>` solution (which I've already implemented) in part because it breaks encapsulation to have a custom element manipulating the DOM of elements outside of it, and also because I am using this in a `contenteditable` block, so that if someone adds text after the F, like `the note <nobr>F or G<my-sharp></my-sharp></nobr> is nice` then the `<nobr>` is covering whitespace, which isn't intended.

A css attribute like `display: inline-character` does not seem to exist, but maybe there is another way?

Comment: A live example of the issue would be nice. It's a bit hard to see why it would break here to begin with.

Comment: Have you considered creating your own font?

Comment: @AHaworth -- yes, though the particular problem requires custom web elements.  Those end up showing a character in their own font but context can change the presentation.

Comment: Did you try `display:inline` for `<my-sharp>`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Supersharp -- the host was displayed as inline, and so was the only subelement in the shadow root -- I did just check setting `style="display: inline;"` on every element, and unfortunately it didn't help; adjacent inline elements can have line breaks between (but thanks for reminding me to triple check that).

Answer (score 1):

I think on the one hand you are overthinking things here but on the other hand you aren't giving enough information on your actual problem. It may be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where you are asking about a perceived solution rather than your actual problem.

Some general things to consider:

You shouldn't be using the `<nobr>` element. It's deprecated. Neither should you create custom elements such as `<my-sharp>`, (unless you are creating web components). Instead use CSS `white-space: nowrap` on a suitable element with a class, such as `<span class="note">...</span>`

Also you don't need a custom element to display a sharp symbol. It can be used directly (F♯) or using an HTML entity: `F&sharp;` = F♯. And when doing this by default there can be no line break between the characters so you wouldn't need `white-space: nowrap`.

If the problem is about the user writing into the `<span class="note">...</span>` (or in your case the `<nobr>...</nobr>`) in a content editable element, it should be possible to programmatically prevent that.

Actually working with `contenteditable` can be quite tricky. Are you writing every thing yourself? It may be much easier to use one of several very capable existing components instead, for example, just to name one: [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/) They provide ways for users to enter special characters such as `♯` and I believe some have features like only allowing specific text in an element.

If this doesn't help you need to show more of the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The HTML Entity for sharp is hideous and there are no commonly supported HTML entities for things like double-sharps or half-flats, etc. all things that musicians use.  And yes, everything is a custom-element because the display is different depending on certain variable features (like user language).  I work in a company that develops custom elements including editors for music.  The problem is specifically about not allowing a line break before an element without adding an additional wrapper, not any perceived XY problem.